# Error 91 when attempting to add control to previously opened form

Tags: forms, excel, userform, vba

I've got two userforms - "PhaseHome" and "ModifyPhases".

I must go through the "PhaseHome" form in order to get to the "ModifyPhases" form. Once on the "ModifyPhases" form, I utilize a combo-box and button for the user to create a new & custom named userform that has a few controls. The code looks like this:

Please Note:

"Phasename" is the custom name the user entered in the earlier combo-box.

```
Sub New_form()

Dim Newphase As VBComponent
Dim ItemBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim AddItem As MSForms.CommandButton

Sheet1.Activate

'Creating the new form
Set Newphase = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
    With Newphase
    .Properties("Height") = 250
    .Properties("Width") = 350
    .Properties("Caption") = Phasename
    .Name = Phasename
    End With


'Inserting the combobox into the dynamically created form
Set ItemBox = Newphase.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
With ItemBox
    .Name = Phasename & "Box"
    .Top = 60
    .Left = 12
    .Width = 140
    .Height = 80
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleOpaque
    .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
End With

'Inserting buttons into the dynamically created form
Set AddItem = Newphase.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
With AddItem
    .Name = "cmd_1"
    .Caption = "Add Line Item"
    .Top = 5
    .Left = 200
    .Width = 110
    .Height = 35
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
End With
```

With that done and the userform created; I now want to add a button to the "PhaseHome" form that allows the user to get to the form we just created.

```
Sheet1.Select
Range("D5").Value = Range("D5").Value + 45

'Add button to Phase Home Form
Dim homeform_button As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim ufObj As UserForm

Set ufObj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Phasehome").Designer
With ufObj
    Set homeform_button = .Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
    With homeform_button
        .Name = "cmd" + Phasename
        .Caption = Phasename
        .Top = Range("D5").Value
        .Left = 45
        .Width = 78
        .Height = 36
        .Font.Size = 8
        .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
    End With
End With

'Making sure we don't overwrite previously existing code when we insert this into PhaseHome
Dim linestart As Integer 

linestart = Range("D8").Value

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("PhaseHome").CodeModule.InsertLines linestart, "Private Sub cmd" & Phasename & "_Click()"
linestart = linestart + 1
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("PhaseHome").CodeModule.InsertLines linestart, "Unload Me"
linestart = linestart + 1
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("PhaseHome").CodeModule.InsertLines linestart, "Sheet2.Activate"
linestart = linestart + 1
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("PhaseHome").CodeModule.InsertLines linestart, "" & Phasename & ".Show"
linestart = linestart + 1
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("PhaseHome").CodeModule.InsertLines linestart, "End Sub"
linestart = linestart + 1

Range("D8").Value = linestart
```

Now the good news is that this code works!.... As long as I run it from the "ModifyPhases" form directly. Once, for the very first time in a session, that I open and close the "PhaseHome" form I start receiving an error 91 (Object variable or With block Variable not set) that points to the

```
Set homeform_button = .Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
```

line everytime I attempt to run the macro again.

Things I've tried:

1. I've made sure that the "PhaseHome" form is unloaded. The button that goes between the userforms always includes an Unload Me, i've also tried unloading "PhaseHome" directly within the macro itself, and also used variables tied to "PhaseHome"'s terminate and Initialize functions to ensure it is unloaded without referencing it directly.
2. After noticing that refreshing the workbook fixed the issue, I discovered some code online (From a source I regretfully forget) that closes and reopens the workbook each time the "ModifyPhases" form is launched which fixes the issue.

   **Sub CloseMe()
       Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "OpenMe"
       ThisWorkbook.Close True
   End Sub**

   **Sub OpenMe()
      ModifyPhases.Show
   End Sub**

I don't know why the code tags aren't working right here.

This works but... causes corruption in the workbook and also seems rather unnecessary. Do you fellows have any theories on why this could be occurring? Thank you!

-Mano

Comment: Why are you attempting to add to the `.Designer`? I think you should be able to add forms to the control *directly*, and I think that would (usually) be preferable.

Comment: Also note some differences you are using both `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook`, when the 91 error raises, are you sure that `ThisWorkbook` **is** the `ActiveWorkbook`? If not, then an object error is probably expected.

Comment: Ultimately I think (and you can clarify, of course) that you probably do not need to use VBE in this case. Do you need to maintain a collection of dynamically added controls? It looks like it would be much easier for you to create the "custom" form, and then modify its properties at run-time, rather than attempting to build a GUI at runtime, dynamically.

Comment: 1. Changing `ThisWorkbook` to `Activeworkbook` did not seem to make a difference. 2. How is it possible to add a control to an existing form without using the Designer? I don't think I've found an example that doesn't involve using the designer.  3. I do not need a collection of the controls you are correct... I modify the properties of the "custom" form at runtime but I cannot add the button to the other (PhaseHOme) form at runtime as it stands.

Comment: 1) OK. 2) `Controls.Add` instead of `Designer.Controls.Add` -- but I don't think this is necessary either way, because it doesn't sound like you really need a dynamic collection of controls. 3) Do you need a dynamic collection of *forms*?  I.e., is the `Newphase` form created only once? Or is it potentially a collection/array and created multiple times? And are you trying to let the user make *permanent* additions/changes to the UI?

Comment: Ah, I apologize I misunderstood your third comment. I DO need to maintain a collection of the controls. The macro may be run many times and each time it is run I need a new custom button for each custom form added to "PhaseHome". If the user later deletes that Phase then the button is just hidden on "Phasehome" but that part seems to work.

Comment: Do you need a collection of *forms*? Or just of buttons?

Comment: I don't need to alter the forms after they are created at all but by definition I do need a collection... same with the buttons so both I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered the issue with my macro. Once my code had finished building my custom userforms at Design time - it was not exiting from design mode on the custom form when I attempted to switch it over to the design mode on the "PhaseHome" userform to edit my buttons resulting in the Error 91. I found that by manually entering design mode (Using code I found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6cdccfa8-0e14-4ad9-b0f6-bbc8cd8091ac/vba-and-vbnet-code-to-turn-off-design-mode-in-excel-application?forum=exceldev) from Mr. Peter Thornton) and then manually exiting design mode using a time delay macro (Shown below) right before my code began placing my button onto the "Phasehome" form worked every time without error.

**I used the time delay macro because entering design mode ends macro execution.**

I discovered this by using the `.hasopendesigner` property ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251487.aspx)) to test my custom form variable right before I tried to enter design mode for my "Phasehome" userform to add my button and found that it was still open. **Just manually exiting design mode did not seem to change this - which is the part I suspect is a bug. This is why I manually entered then manually exited design mode.**

I'm not certain but i'm leaning towards this being a bug within VBA Userforms as it has aggressively resisted any other form of troubleshooting besides a workbook reload as described previously.

Here is my code after I have completed the design of my custom userform (*Please note selections are done because I wanted to control what the user saw during this process and are mostly unnecessary*):

```
Sheet1.Select

Dim linestart As Integer 'Making sure we don't overwrite our code when we insert it into PhaseHome

linestart = Range("D8").Value

ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("PhaseHome").CodeModule.InsertLines linestart, "Private Sub cmd" & Phasename & "_Click()"
linestart = linestart + 1
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("PhaseHome").CodeModule.InsertLines linestart, "Unload Me"
linestart = linestart + 1
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("PhaseHome").CodeModule.InsertLines linestart, "Sheet2.Activate"
linestart = linestart + 1
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("PhaseHome").CodeModule.InsertLines linestart, "" & Phasename & ".Show"
linestart = linestart + 1
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("PhaseHome").CodeModule.InsertLines linestart, "End Sub"
linestart = linestart + 1

Range("D8").Value = linestart
Range("D5").Value = Range("D5").Value + 45
Range("D10").Value = Phasename

Sheet2.Select
Range("A1").Select
Call Design_mode_on
End Sub
```

TIME DELAY MACRO:

```
Sub Design_mode_on()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Design_mode_off"
    EnterExitDesignMode True 'Enter Design Mode
End Sub




Sub Design_mode_off()
   EnterExitDesignMode False 'Exit Design Mode
   Call second_newphase
End Sub



Sub EnterExitDesignMode(bEnter As Boolean)
Dim cbrs As CommandBars
Const sMsoName As String = "DesignMode"

    Set cbrs = Application.CommandBars
    If Not cbrs Is Nothing Then
        If cbrs.GetEnabledMso(sMsoName) Then
            If bEnter <> cbrs.GetPressedMso(sMsoName) Then
                cbrs.ExecuteMso sMsoName
                Stop
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

\TIME DELAY MACRO:

```
Sub second_newphase()  'Divided this module in 2 due to some weird form interactions

Sheet1.Select

Phasename = Range("D10").Value
Range("D10").Clear
Dim homeform_button As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim ufObj As UserForm

EnterExitDesignMode False 'Exit again just for good measure hehe

Set ufObj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Phasehome").Designer
With ufObj
    Set homeform_button = .Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
    With homeform_button
        .Name = "cmd" + Phasename
        .Caption = Phasename
        .Top = Range("D5").Value
        .Left = 45
        .Width = 78
        .Height = 36
        .Font.Size = 8
        .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
    End With
End With

Sheet2.Select
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make no mistake about it: Modifying controls at run-time, and especially *adding forms at run-time*, is a high-level VBA exercise, and I think that it simply is beyond what you're currently capable of. (Please don't take this the wrong way, I don't mean to condescend)

> I need a new custom button for each custom form added to "PhaseHome".

I'm gathering that this is the hang-up, and also source of error. So...

**Is there an easier way??**

Let's ditch that idea altogether!

Use a different control type that is more amenable to modifications at run-time. Buttons are tricky because they require each their own `_Click` event handler. Instead of adding buttons for each phase, just add a new item to a `ComboBox` control, and leverage its `_Change` (or some other) event as a method of user-input.

IOW, instead of expecting the user to press a button that displays a form, just let them select the form from a ComboBox!

Then, invoking that ComboBox's `_Change` event, refer back to the dict/collection of properties, and display the "Phaseform" object where you can modify it's controls at runtime, as needed.

Now you have a relatively generic form that will be used for *any possible phase*.

The `List` property of the Combobox is itself dynamic, and has a `_Change` event handler which you can use!

```
Private Sub cbox_PhaseNames_Change()

    MsgBox Me.Value  'Show the value which is selected, for debugging

    'Modify the Newphase userform. There is only one form, and its properties
    ' will be modified based on the selection from the cBox_Phasenames control

   Newphase.Caption = Me.Value

   'If you need to change other controls, you can probably do that here, too
```

End Sub

## Example

I created some crude example ([download from Google Drive if you'd like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1v0s8ldwHRYdkl5OFZpNFF6ZWM/view?usp=sharing)), using only two user forms. `Phasehome` implements described above, and the `Phaseform` can be modified (e.g., it's `Caption`) based on the selection in the ComboBox on `PhaseHome`.

**NOTE**: You're using 3 forms at least, please make note that I'm only using 2, what my example does for `Pagehome` really is probably more applicable to your `ModifyPhases` form, so take note of that and modify accordingly.

[image]

This would be how I set up the code for `Phasehome`:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cbox_Phasenames_Change()
    Dim val$, bFound As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    
    'crude validation:
    val = Me.cbox_Phasenames.Value
    For i = 0 To Me.cbox_Phasenames.ListCount - 1
        If val = Me.cbox_Phasenames.List(i) Then
            bFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If Not bFound Then Exit Sub 'Avoid errors
    
    'Modify the PhaseForm:
    With phaseForm
        .Caption = val
        .Show
    End With
    
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   
    'Very simple example, allows duplicates, which you probably want to avoid
    Me.cbox_Phasenames.AddItem Me.TextBox1.Value

End Sub
```

And here is the code for `Phaseform`, I've commented a few items, but using the `Initialize` event to assign the properties you've set up:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Height = 250
    Me.Width = 350
    'Me.Caption = ""   '## This is set in the calling procedure
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .Top = 60
        .Left = 12
        .Width = 140
        .Height = 80
        .Font.Size = 8
        .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
    End With
    With Me.CommandButton1
        '### There is no need to assign a dynamic Name property to this control
        '.Name = "cmd" + Phasename
        .Caption = ""
        .Top = Range("D5").Value
        .Left = 45
        .Width = 78
        .Height = 36
        .Font.Size = 8
        .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
    End With
    
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    MsgBox "Does something..."
End Sub
```

**Note:** If there are additional properties that you need to persist during runtime can be done via Static variables and using possibly Collection or Dictionary object to assist with organizing what's needed. Keep the "list" of phases in an Array, and keep their relevant properties in a dict/collection, etc. If absolutely necessary you can store some things in a hidden worksheet, or in a `Name` in the workbook, or in CustomXMLPart, etc. -- there's lots of ways you can conceivably persist metadata beyond the user session, so that the changes will be available tomorrow, next week, etc.